# even though it is executing correctly but while using scope in bean definition it is giving warning error

Tags: java, xml, spring

**spring.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE beans PUBLIC "-//SPRING//DTD BEAN//EN" "http://www.springframework.org/dtd/spring-beans.dtd">

<beans>
    <bean id="triangle" class="com.diwakar.Triangle" autowire="byName" scope="singleton">

    </bean>

    <bean id="pointA" class="com.diwakar.Point">
        <property name="x" value="0" />
        <property name="y" value="0" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="pointB" class="com.diwakar.Point">
        <property name="x" value="20" />
        <property name="y" value="0" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="pointC" class="com.diwakar.Point">
        <property name="x" value="30" />
        <property name="y" value="10" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

I am attaching snapshot below to make things clear because here it seems everything right, it might be silly question but curious to know.

[spring-xml-snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C73sx.png)

Comment: What is the warning then? Paste some output.

Comment: @mattias Attribute "scope" must be declared for element type "bean".

Comment: @mattias I have attached the snapshot also, in that you can see that red underline for scope.
Even though everything executes as expected but wants to know why red cross there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a DTD from Spring 1.x: http://docs.spring.io/dtd/spring-beans.dtd (dated 01-Nov-2006)

The `scope` attribute was added in Spring 2.0: http://docs.spring.io/dtd/spring-beans-2.0.dtd (dated 03-May-2007)

Spring 3.0 switched to use namespaces and XSD: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/xsd-config.html

There is actually XSD files for Spring 2.0, 2.5, 3.0, 3.1, 3.2, 4.0, 4.1, 4.2, and 4.3 at this time. See http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/

Switch to XSD and the appropriate version of Spring.
Or at least switch to the 2.0 version of the DTD.